# How to show full app long name?

Tags: iphone, deployment

Please view below image and help me (full text is "FashionSearch"):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The icon is limited to the amount of characters is can show in the label - you need to make your label shorter

http://blog.bahrenburgs.com/2009/11/mystery-of-iphone-application-title.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can however, change the display name in Xcode, by changing the display name in your info.plist file.  Look for "Bundle Display Name".